# Adding import button to music player

Tags: button, import, processing, minim

I'm trying to make it possible to make a functional import button, by this I mean I click the button, the file browser pops up and I can click a song then the player can play it. Just like any other music player. Here is a basic view of my code so far excluding the classes:

```
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.*; 
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;
boolean play;
boolean repeat;
int k;
String filename;//
Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;

Pics p;
Mechs m;
Importbt b;
ArrayList<Songs> s;
int i=0;
void setup() {
size(600, 400);
b=new Importbt();
m=new Mechs();
p=new Pics();
p.Thepics();

minim=new Minim(this);
s = new ArrayList();
s.add(new Songs(player, "SONG 1", "SONG 1"));
s.add(new Songs(player, "SONG 2", "SONG 2"));
s.add(new Songs(player, "SONG 3", "SONG 3"));
s.add(new Songs(player, "SONG 4", "SONG 4"));
k = s.size()-1;
}
void draw() {
background(0);
p.getFunction();
}

void fileSelected(File selection) {
if (selection == null) {
} 
else {
filename = selection.getAbsolutePath();
player = minim.loadFile(filename);//loads the file
// s.add(k, new Songs(player, filename, "a song"));
//s.get(k).playmusic();
s.add(new Songs(player, filename, "ftyu"));
s.get(k).waveform();//function from my songs class
player.play();//plays the file
```

As for my class if its needed

```
class Songs {
AudioPlayer song; 
String directory;
String songName;
Songs(AudioPlayer song, String directory, String songName) {

song=minim.loadFile(directory);

this.song=song;
this.songName=songName;
}
void waveform() {
for (int j = 1; j < song.bufferSize() - 1; j++)
{
  if (j>0) {

    line(j, 214  + song.left.get(j)*50, j+1, 214 + song.left.get(j+1)*50);
    //waves from the left.
    stroke( 255, 0, 0 );  //this is the colour of the first line (red)
    line(j, 214 + song.right.get(j)*50, j+1, 214 + song.right.get(j+1)*50);
    //waves from the right.
    stroke(255, 255, 0);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you going:

```
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;

float buttonX;
float buttonY;
float buttonW;
float buttonH;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;

String filename;

void setup() {

  textSize(24);

  frame.setResizable(false);

  background(255);

  size(600, 200);

  fill(0);
  stroke(0);
  noFill();

  buttonW = 200;
  buttonH = 50;
  buttonX = width - width/2 - buttonW/2;
  buttonY = height/2 - buttonH/2;

  // Minim stuff
  minim = new Minim(this);
}

void draw() {

  background(255);
  fill(0);

  rectMode(CORNER);

  rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonW, buttonH);

  fill(255);

  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("Import File", buttonX+35, buttonY+30);
}

void mouseClicked() {
  if (mouseX>buttonX && mouseX < buttonX+buttonW && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY+buttonH) {
    selectInput("Import music file", "fileSelected");
  }
}

/* Taken from Processing.org */
void fileSelected(File selection) {
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Window was closed or user hit cancel");
  } else {
    filename = selection.getAbsolutePath();
    player = minim.loadFile(filename);
    player.play();
    println("User selected " + filename);
  }
}

// stop minim and the player.
void stop() {
  player.close();
  minim.stop();
  super.stop();
}
```

This is a very simple example. All this does is creates objects for `Minim` and `AudioPlayer` and then uses the file selection mechanism to feed the path and name of the file to `loadFile(filename)`. Then if the file is a legitimate audio file (I only tested with a `.wav` file) then it plays it. After it is done, the player is stopped.

Keep in mind that this does not do any error checking or anything so if you chose a `.jpeg` file, for example, it will throw exceptions. You should play with these things to try and see how you can *streamline* your player.

One thing you should try and understand is that this is all very straightforward. The filename is simply a `String` and nothing extremely complicated.

You can find a tutorial for `Minim` here: http://artandtech.aalto.fi/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/minim.pdf

**UPDATE: SINE WAVES WORKING WITH THE SELECTED SONG**

I have updated my code that I provided here to work with the wave thing that you have going. I added a `boolean` which becomes `true` when a file is selected. Now you will have to tweak this code to work with multiple files. This is just an example.

**UPDATE 2: IMPLEMENTED THE CODE TO WORK WITH YOUR SONGS CLASS**

```
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;

float buttonX;
float buttonY;
float buttonW;
float buttonH;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;
ArrayList<Songs> s;
int k;

String filename;

boolean isSelected = false;

void setup() {

  s = new ArrayList();

  textSize(24);

  frame.setResizable(false);

  background(255);

  size(600, 600);

  fill(0);
  stroke(0);
  noFill();

  buttonW = 200;
  buttonH = 50;
  buttonX = width - width/2 - buttonW/2;
  buttonY = height/2 - buttonH/2;

  // Minim stuff
  minim = new Minim(this);
}

void draw() {

  background(255);
  fill(0);

  rectMode(CORNER);

  rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonW, buttonH);

  fill(255);

  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("Import File", buttonX+35, buttonY+30);

  if (isSelected) {
    s.get(k).waveform();
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  if (mouseX>buttonX && mouseX < buttonX+buttonW && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY+buttonH) {
    selectInput("Import music file", "fileSelected");
  }
}

/* Taken from Processing.org */
void fileSelected(File selection) {
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Window was closed or user hit cancel");
  } 
  else {
    filename = selection.getAbsolutePath();
    s.add(new Songs(player, filename, "Filename"));
    isSelected = true;
  }
}

// stop minim and the player.
void stop() {
  player.close();
  minim.stop();
  super.stop();
}

class Songs {
  AudioPlayer song; 
  String directory;
  String songName;
  Songs(AudioPlayer song, String directory, String songName) {

    song=minim.loadFile(directory);    

    this.song=song;
    this.songName=songName;
    song.play();
  }
  void waveform() {
    for (int j = 1; j < song.bufferSize() - 1; j++)
    {
      if (j>0) {

        line(j, 214  + song.left.get(j)*50, j+1, 214 + song.left.get(j+1)*50);
        //waves from the left.
        stroke( 255, 0, 0 );  //this is the colour of the first line (red)
        line(j, 214 + song.right.get(j)*50, j+1, 214 + song.right.get(j+1)*50);
        //waves from the right.
        stroke(255, 255, 0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The reason you see a flash of red and then nothing the way you had your code set up was because it reads the `waveform()` method and goes through the `for` loop really fast and then moves on to the rest of the operations like playing the song. Putting it in `draw()` like I've done helps you avoid that.

Comment: @user3423784 Check out this answer and let me know if you need any help with this.

Comment: Ty for that, ive got the import working,  but the only issue I have now is that when I play an imported song, my sound waves I made doesn't play with the imported song, I tired to define it as much as I can.

Comment: @user3423784 I don't understand what you mean. What sound waves? Are you trying to play two songs simultaneously?

Comment: You know how music players such as windows media player has those animations when you play a song? Like waves...That is what I have added in my player. Here is what they look like:http://www.kungfupunk.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/music-visualization-1.jpg
And the waves will work with the songs in my arraylist but not the songs I get from the import button.

Comment: @user3423784 okay. Why not add the imported songs to your ArrayList?

Comment: @user3423784 Also how exactly are you adding the songs to the ArrayList? And what do you mean when you say *it doesn't work*?

Comment: I tried adding the songs to the arraylist, when I say it doesn't work I mean that when the imported song is loaded,itdoesnt follow the wave format,it will play,but therewill be no waves when it is playing.
ArrayList<Songs> s;
s.add(new Songs(player, filename,"imported song"));
That will just make the imported music play,however when I  add a variable as such called k, which gets the my wave function from my class
s.get(k).waveform();
player.play();
The end result being the imported song plays,there is this flash which shows my waves,but it is only there when the song starts for some reason :s.

Comment: @user3423784 Can you update your question with all of your code so I can then see where its messing up?

Comment: @user3423784 Alright, I'll check it out and update the answer.

Comment: @user3423784 updated the code again to work with your Songs class. This should now be sufficient for you to implement it for more songs, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that, you're really helpful, although, the song.play(); is causing all the music I already have on the arraylist to all play when I play my player. The waves are starting to work for my imported songs

Comment: @user3423784 No problem at all. So this is fixed then or do you still have questions on this problem?

Comment: This is fixed yes, all I going to do now is make sure when I upload the import, I'm able to pause it etc.

Comment: @user3423784 Awesome. Could you accept the answer then and if you have any other problem with the code, leave a comment here or open a new question?